# How do I know if my long sms is sent properly?

Tags: iphone, sms

I've heard of [concatenated SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS) whereby SMSes longer than 160 alphanumerals are broken down, sent separately, and then recombined on the receiver's phone.

How do we know whether our long SMS is sent (and received) properly?

What happens if the receiving phone does not support concatenated SMS?

Comment: This forum could help
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4604769

Comment: @AppleDevX, hmm it doesn't seem to say how the sender can know whether the message is sent properly...

Comment: I suspect the only way is if the receiver tells you. As that post suggests it depends on an individual's carrier. This being the case if at least one person you are sending a long text to gets it ok, then you do not have a problem your end. Therefore I suggest you do not worry about it until someone tells you they did not get your message correctly and possibly as mixed up multiple Msgs.